# Accessing Sharepoint 2007 documents outside network

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I just installed MOSS 2007 and configure it on a machine. The machine is not in a domain.

When I try to create a new document in my document library (Server is on a remote location and my laptop is not a part of the domain), MS Word 2007 opens, asks me for login credentials 3 times and then disappears leaving me with a new blank word document.

Is there any way to enable remote access of MOSS 2007 documents?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the Windows AD as an authentication model, you can go with FBA (Forms Based Authentication). See this article: [Configure forms-based authentication (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262201.aspx)